# Regex: match SQL PRINT blocks with quoted text in it

Tags: sql, regex, newline, non-greedy

I have the following text I am trying match using regular expressions:

> PRINT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 111) + ' ' +
>   CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   108)
>                   + ' -Test Mode : ' + (CASE WHEN @turbo_mode_ind = 1 THEN
>   'some text ''test'' some more text.'
>                                                                           ELSE 'and even more text ''temp'' when
>   will it stop ?' END)
>
> PRINT 'text don''t text'
>
> PRINT 'text ''test2'' text'

What I want to match is:

> PRINT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 111) + ' ' +
>   CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   108)
>                   + ' -Test Mode : ' + (CASE WHEN @turbo_mode_ind = 1 THEN
>   'some text ''test''
>
> PRINT 'text ''test2''

So basically I want to match:

- starting at PRINT
- each char that comes after PRINT (.*)
- inclusive line-breaks (don't stop at
  line-breaks)
- with \'{2}\w+\'{2} at the end of the
  match
- non-greedy (.*?)
- AND no empty line(s) between PRINT
  and \'{2}\w+\'{2}

I have already compsed this, but it still matches empty line(s):

`PRINT.*?\'{2}\w+\'{2}(?!\n\s*\n)`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit after comment:**

Looking at the requirements again I could not come up with a single regex solution quickly. In your comments you mention that you are using C#.

A possible solution would therfore be to first split the string at blank lines and then extracting the text.

Something like this:

```
string pattern = @"^$";

foreach (string result in Regex.Split(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline) 
{
    Regex rxFindSql = Regex(@"PRINT.*?\'{2}\w+?\'{2}", RegexOptions.SingleLine)       
    MatchCollection matches = rxFindSql.Matches(result);
}
```

This should do the trick but I did not test the code.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure about `\w+`, as it doesn't allow spaces. But then again, the OP wrote it, so maybe it should be a single word.

Comment: Did you put the first block on one line or something, because I only get PRINT 'text ''test2'' as a match. 
In other words, the regex doesn't get passed line-breaks.
FYI i am using the regex component in C#:
new Regex(@"PRINT.*?\'{2}\w+?\'{2}", RegexOptions.Multiline)

Comment: Sorry, I just copied the text form the browser not realizing there were no line-breaks in the first sample. I have will edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Yep, I also came to the conclusion that it probably won't work in one RegEx so I've used your code and guess what ? It works perfectly.